# No se reinicia el autoincremento en id de un registro DB

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Cree una tabla usuario que el idusuario fuera autoincremental, ingrese valores de prueba y al eliminarlos e ingresar un nuevo registro valido el id sigue donde quedo como si estuvieran los otros registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando elimine un registro el id se modifique?

Comment: no deberias hacerlo.! porque es para llevar un registro unico si borras el id de referencia como llevas un control o orden? ejemplo venga un cliente a reclamar por una factura #5 y como moviste todo ya esta factura #5 no existe...

Comment: Si es autoincremental y primaria solo esa columna deberia incrementarse en cada insert, o sea, ya lo hace bien... en caso contrario piensa el lio que tendras si reinicias el conteo como dice Alfabravo el dia que se solapen permisos de los usuarios por lo que sea, o archivos o cosas vinculadas a ese id sustituido con otos valores de otro usuario. No es óptimo aprovechar ids... mientras estas de pruebas vale, pero cuando la saques a la luz no lo hagas

Comment: Te toca reiniciar el conteo. Ese es un atributo de la tabla

Comment: Otro tema relacionado es porque eliminarlos realmente?  Puede poner una columna de activo con un valor booleano, y así saber si estan o no activos, asi conservaras su información por si acaso (a menos que te pidan expresamente borrar los datos por la ley xxxx, entonces al borrarlos recuerda borrar tambien todo lo que tenga relacion con su id en otras tablas o lugares)

Comment: Gracias por lo comentarios, me hicieron entender bien algunas cosas y analizar otras para agregarlas como la parte de activo e inactivo. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 4):

Como lo estás haciendo, si realmente quieres reiniciar el conteo, debes reiniciar el atributo de la tabla donde la BD va llevando la cuenta. Los registros se van creando y para cada uno, la BD pregunta "qué valor sigue?" y lo pone. No es que revise cuáles hay y de acuerdo a eso asigne. ¡¡Eso sería muy lento!!

La consulta que buscas para reiniciar ese conteo es

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```